# Objective-c: Read plist and sort in inputted order

Tags: objective-c, sorting, plist

I have a plist in which the contained dictionaries, strings and arrays are in a specific order. However, when I run my app, they are in a different order.

Is there a way to retain the originally inputted order?

I know there's a sort descriptor, but isn't that just alphabetically/numerically?

Answer (score 2):

If your root plist object is a dictionary, then it is inherently unordered. To get a specific ordering back out, you either need an array or to sort by some key after reading the plist back in.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries will always be unordered, but the arrays within your plist should all retain order.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers suggest, dictionaries are unordered.
You can either use arrays or specify numeric keys for your dictionary items.

```
1_Button -> Dictionary describing button
2_Label  -> Dictionary describing label
```

Now you can order your dictionary in code.
That's how i've been doing in one of my games where all of the UI was inside the plist file of the current theme.

HTH.